# Difference between * and + in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am quite new to python and practicing a few regular expression from [google python exercies](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) 
A section from there says :

> **Repetition**
>
> Things get more interesting when you use `+` and `*` to specify repetition
>   in the pattern
>
> `+` -- 1 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left, e.g. `i+` = one or more `i`'s
>
> `*` -- 0 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left

So I decided to try out some samples .

```
import re
text="xx1  2   3xx"
match = re.search(r'\d\s+\d\s+\d',text)
match.group()
```

and this yields the following output :

```
1  2   3
```

and to understand the difference between `*` and `+` I tried this :

```
import re
text="xx1  2   3xx"
match = re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d',text)
match.group()
```

and yielded the output :

```
1  2   3
```

(the same as output 1)

I still wonder,whether these : `*` and `+` really have same function? If not examples are much appreciated!

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: I don't get it. You have included the answer to your question in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like it says, `*` matches zero or more, `+` matches one or more.  But you only tested them on a case where there is more than one space, which means they both apply.  Compare how your regexes work on `"xx12   3xx"` where there are *zero* spaces between the first two digits.

Comment: the second snippet gives a correct match..since * matches zero or more whitespace and this is true for the text u gave..?

Comment: Yes, the second one does, but what about the first?  The point is that this is the difference: using `*` will match when there are zero spaces and using `+` will not.

Answer (score 4):

`*` matches 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, while `+` 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE.

```
>>> re.findall(r'a\s*b', 'ab')
['ab']
>>> re.findall(r'a\s+b', 'ab')
[]

>>> re.findall(r'a\s*b', 'a b')
['a b']
>>> re.findall(r'a\s+b', 'a b')
['a b']
```

Comment: the only difference between them is for + :atleast 1 or more repetition and for *: 0 or more repetition..correct ?

Comment: @DiljitPR, Yes, it is.

Comment: @falsetru You made my life simple. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is nice article](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

- `*` matches 0 or more

  > Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.
- `+` matches at least 1 or more

  > Causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE. ab+ will match ‘a’ followed by any non-zero number of ‘b’s; it will not match just ‘a’.

[Python docs to refer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)